# How can i invoke parallel browsers from different machines using selenium grid?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-grid

I tried to invoke multiple browsers from different machines using selenium grid but it's not working. 
For eg. I have 5 machines and I need to invoke 2 methods using different browsers from each machine at the same time. I have two methods:

```
    @test ()
    Public void a(){

    }
    @test()
    Public void b(){
    }
```

Using testng how can it be done?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What did you tried ? Which errors did you have ?

Comment: Using parallel='methods' attribute in testng.xml i have executed the same as testng suite. but the issue is method a and b are invoked in different machines instead of invoking both methods parallel in same machine.

Comment: You should edit your post to explain **precisely** what you tried and what you obtained. See [ask] to maximize the chances to get a valuable feedback to your question